# Rename the dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
lis=[{'0':'A','1':'B','2':'c','3':'d','4':'f','5':'g'},{'0':'A','1':'B','2':'c','3':'d','4':'f','5':'g'},{'0':'A','1':'B','2':'c','3':'d','4':'f','5':'g'}]
df=pd.DataFrame(lis)

df1

df=pd.DataFrame(lis,columns=list('ABCDFG'))
```

I want to rename the columns of dataframe but while renamaing getting below dataframe withall nan values

```
      A B   C   D   F   G
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: `df1.columns = df.iloc[0].str.upper()` ? or `df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.nan,columns=df.iloc[0].str.upper(),index=df.index)` depending on what you need

Comment: `df.columns = list('ABCDFG')`